# INSERT INTO (SELECT with many columns joins(with more joins, sums...), coalesces,month...)

Tags: mysql, sql

my query is:

```
INSERT into per_m (ANO,REM_I,QTD)
VALUES
(SELECT '2014-04-01' as ANO ,rem_i.ID as REM_I,

COALESCE(
        per_m.QTD-coalesce(rem_o.QTD+rem_intl.QTD,rem_o.QTD,rem_intl.QTD,0)
                  ,
        rem_i.QTD-coalesce(rem_o.QTD+rem_intl.QTD,rem_o.QTD,rem_intl.QTD,0)
         )as QTD


FROM rem_i 
left JOIN
incom on incom.ID=rem_i.INCOM
left JOIN
per_m on per_m.REM_I=rem_i.ID

left JOIN
(SELECT rem_o.REM_I, SUM(rem_o.QTD)as QTD from rem_o
LEFT JOIN outcom
ON (outcom.ID=rem_o.OUTCOM)
WHERE month(outcom.DATA)='03'
GROUP BY rem_o.REM_I)as rem_o

on(rem_o.REM_I=rem_i.ID )


left JOIN
(SELECT rem_intl.REM_I, SUM(rem_intl.QTD)as QTD from rem_intl
LEFT JOIN intl
ON (intl.ID=rem_intl.INTL)
WHERE month(intl.DATA)='03'
GROUP BY rem_intl.REM_I)as rem_intl

on(rem_intl.REM_I=rem_i.ID )


WHERE month(per_m.ANO)='03'or month(incom.DATA)='03'
GROUP BY REM_I)
```

and the error is at line 3: a void message #1064 appears.I've tested only the select and it is all ok. I never work with insert into **SELECT. Any Idea for what can be wrong?**

and does someone know any page where I can emulate db interfaces (like jsfiddle)but with querys and tables for sharing some samples that I'm testing the query above?

Thanks.

Comment: You have what is probably the correct answer.  As a general troubleshooting method, when you are going to write a query like this, write the select part first and make sure it works.  Then, when you convert it to an insert query, if things go wrong, you have fewer things to look at.

Comment: @DanBracuk That appears to be what the OP did

Comment: @DanBracuk as in my question, I've test that select with success, insert into is the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, as @Strawberry correctly points out, use [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) to construct samples.  In regards to your query, remove the word `VALUES`.  The correct syntax is:

```
INSERT INTO tablename (columns) SELECT samenumberofcolumns...
```

In your case, this should work:

```
INSERT into per_m (ANO,REM_I,QTD)
SELECT '2014-04-01' as ANO ,rem_i.ID as REM_I,

COALESCE(
        per_m.QTD-coalesce(rem_o.QTD+rem_intl.QTD,rem_o.QTD,rem_intl.QTD,0)
                  ,
        rem_i.QTD-coalesce(rem_o.QTD+rem_intl.QTD,rem_o.QTD,rem_intl.QTD,0)
         )as QTD


FROM rem_i 
left JOIN
incom on incom.ID=rem_i.INCOM
left JOIN
per_m on per_m.REM_I=rem_i.ID

left JOIN
(SELECT rem_o.REM_I, SUM(rem_o.QTD)as QTD from rem_o
LEFT JOIN outcom
ON (outcom.ID=rem_o.OUTCOM)
WHERE month(outcom.DATA)='03'
GROUP BY rem_o.REM_I)as rem_o

on(rem_o.REM_I=rem_i.ID )


left JOIN
(SELECT rem_intl.REM_I, SUM(rem_intl.QTD)as QTD from rem_intl
LEFT JOIN intl
ON (intl.ID=rem_intl.INTL)
WHERE month(intl.DATA)='03'
GROUP BY rem_intl.REM_I)as rem_intl

on(rem_intl.REM_I=rem_i.ID )


WHERE month(per_m.ANO)='03'or month(incom.DATA)='03'
GROUP BY REM_I
```